# How to know the exact selected version of TLS server

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I want to ask regarding the following case TLS client supports v1.2 and v1.3. Is possible that the client firstly only send in the client hello minimum supported version as TLS1.3 with specific ciphers and if the server selects other version(1.2) then the client resend the client hello message with minimum and maximum version of 1.2 ? I want to know if there's any openssl function to know the selected tls version from server side ?
as far as I've seen there's SSL_connect failed (sslv3 alert handshake failure) in such case so how could I know from that exactly which version was selected by the server ? Is **sslv3 alert handshake failure** specific for such case when server selects other version then supported by the client ? I need to know whether I can rely on this error message to know for sure handshake doesn't failed due to other issue and retrigger handshake with 1.2 version

I know about other possibility to use `

```
SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(TLS1_2_VERSION)`
```

and

```
SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version(TLS1_3_VERSION)
```

then the server should select 1.3 if supports otherwise 1.2 which seems more straightforward.
Please let me know if solution 1 is possible or option2 should be applied.

Comment: handshake_failure(40) doesn't always mean wrong protocol version, there are several possible causes. There is another alert, protocol_version(70), which is specific but is not often used. In either case if you get an alert it doesn't tell the client what version(s) the server does support, only that the server possibly or definitely does NOT support the version(s) offered. The approach of offering all versions _you_ support and letting the server choose the highest, if it supports _any_ offered version, is standard and optimal -- and is OpenSSL's default.

Comment: thank you @dave_thompson_085, what exactly means that it is not often used ? what it depends on whether alert with code 70 or 40 is added in the error queue in such case ? can the sever set something for it or is it entirely down to openssl implementation ?

Comment: The server decides what alert code to send in what cases, and in most version incompatibility cases I have investigated or tested the server has used the more general handshake_failure(40) not the more specific protocol_version(70). I don't know why, but they did, and OpenSSL client just reports what the server sent. Not _all_ use 40; an _OpenSSL server_ in particular does use 70 -- which tells you clearly the version(s) you tried is(are) NOT supported, but as I said doesn't tell you what version(s) IS(ARE) supported.